# Function that prints certain letters of a given string

Tags: python, string, function, return

I am trying to make a 'def' function that takes a list of random strings, and a separate list of random numbers, and will return a list of all strings that end with one of the letters in the given letter list.
**Ex:
function 'lastLetter' takes two parameters: 'str1', a list of random strings, and 'letters', a list of random letters, and returns all strings in 'str1' that end with a letter in 'letters'**.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: @JohnGordon I only have the first line, "def hasFinalLetter(strList, letters)". I am stuck on anything after that including how to have it take in the two separate parameters. After that I should be able to figure it out

Comment: @j1-lee For example, str1 = ["Horse", "Cow", "Pig"] and and letters = ["a", "b", "e"] and the function will print out the word "Horse" since it ends with one of the letters in 'letters'.

Comment: @uzziclip Now that makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension, indexing, and `in`:

```py
def has_final_letter(words, letters):
    letters = set(letters) # you can omit this
    return [word for word in words if word[-1] in letters]

str1 = ["Horse", "Cow", "Pig"]
letters = ["a", "b", "e"] # or letters = 'abe'

print(has_final_letter(str1, letters)) # ['Horse']
```

Of course this would result in an error if you have an empty string. To avoid that, you can insert `word and` between `if` and `word[-1]`:

```py
[word for word in words if word and word[-1] in letters]
```

(Now reading out this sentence, full of `word`s, feels a little funny lol.)

---

If you want a full `for` loop version:

```py
def has_final_letter(words, letters):
    output = []
    for word in words:
        if word == '': # check if word is empty
            continue # skip this empty word
        for letter in letters:
            if word[-1] == letter:
                output.append(word)
    return output
```

Comment: wait haha, i think i got it. the wording in your statement works, i just know i couldnt come up with something like that on my own. I just tried **def hasFinalLetter(strList, letters):
    for word in strList:
        if word[-1] in letters:
            return word** and it works. but sure you can provide it if wanted

Comment: @uzziclip Aha that would return only one string; i.e., if the input list was `['Horse', 'Moose', 'Mouse']`, then that would only return `'Horse'`.

Comment: yup, thought i was a genius but i just realized that. this whole function stuff is new to me lol

Comment: okay thats very nice actually. some if its still a little much but the for loop makes it a lot easier to understand. thank you very much appreciate your time

Comment: `Now reading out this sentence, full of word, feels a little funny lol.)` - upvote! :P